# MySQL > SSMS 2012 Linked Server "Requested conversion is not supported."

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion, linked-server, msdasql

This little gem has kept me going for a wee while now and I'm still not much further forward.

Environment

- SSMS 2012 SP1 (target) (Server 2012 64 bit)
- MySQL (source)
- Linked server using ODBC 5.3 64bit Unicode driver

I am trying to port the tables from MySQL onto SSMS.
A majority of the tables work fine....until I hit a column that is cast > 8000 chars.

As I was having an issue I tried to just select the offending Columnm

Running a simple

```
SELECT RogueCol  FROM LinkServer...MyTbl
```

returns the error

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkServer" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].RogueCol" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkServer".
```

So I then tried

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkServer, 'SELECT RogueCol  FROM MyTbl')
```

This returns the same error

I'm totally confused as I cannot seem to even view the data in SSMS, let alone SELECT it into a table (I have a script that will cast the fields according to some rules based on their original MySQL castings)

As I say, for a majority of other fields its not an issue.

The MySQL casting of the RogueCol is varchar(32767)

The settings enabled on the MSDASQL Provider is:

- Nested Queries
- Level Zero Only
- Allow Inprocess
- Supports 'Like'

So far I've tried a raft of things which I've 'discovered' on various forums including:

- CASTING, CONVERTING, LEFT, LTRIM(RTRIM()) on the actual call.
- Tried also restricting it to a TOP 1 record (LEN = 45,  Doesn't have any white space or foreign characters in the string)
- Set up the ANSI version of the ODBC driver
- Various settings within the ODBC driver (Allow Big Result sets, changing Character sets,    Limit Columns to 32 bit, Pad char with space among others)

Can I call upon your collective knowledge and request some further suggestions please as this driving me nuts?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

So guys and girls, no responses

I ended up having to talk to the DBA responsible for the MySQL DB and asked him to alter the casting of the RogueCol from varchar(32767) to TEXT

Job jobbed

Answer (score 0):

If the linked server is not available for editing, you can always use cast(RogueCol as text) in OPENQUERY

```
SELECT 
RogueCol
FROM OPENQUERY([LinkServer],
'
SELECT 
cast (RogueCol as text) as RogueCol
FROM public.MyTbl
')
```